# How do I lay out my content divs in a similar manner to Facebook Timeline?

Tags: html, css, layout

I like the layout that Facebook Timeline has with the staggered two column posts.  I have tried to create the same layout with just standard `div`s and floats.  The floats work well when floating to one side, but not to the other.  Considering there are blocks of multiple heights, how do you suggest I best tackle this layout?  It would be used for a blog, and I am aware that someone has created a WordPress template on this, but is it possible to distil the layout into its simplest form?  After using Chrome's Developer window on my Timeline and the WordPress template, I am struggling to find the appropriate CSS code and need help.

I'll put what I have as a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pKFBp/).  I've added extra blocks if you need them to make sure.

Comment: It is for this reason that I advise against not using tables...so much extra work is going into this when it could be solved by using a table.

Comment: However, with a table, I need specific control over each block height.    If I knew the height of each block beforehand, I would be as sound as a pound.  Since I don't, as it will be for a blog, using a table would cause potentially more problems, even with rowspan.  I need it to be fluid, to flow.  The example I posted works up to block 5 and doesn't allow anything to float behind it.

Comment: [Here](http://www.portablehtml.com/2012/09/how-to-build-facebook-timeline-with.html) is another timeline implementation using jquery, dust.js and webf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have to have the containers on the left be floated and cleared left and the ones on the right be floated and cleared right. You can do this either with javascript or whatever your server side language you use. something quick in jquery would be like this.

(a completed fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/gK2Vn/ I was going for the bare bones of the question..)

```
.item {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
.item.right {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}

var left_column_height = 0;
var right_column_height = 0;
var items = $('.item');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items.eq(i).height(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 10);
    if (left_column_height > right_column_height) {
        right_column_height+= items.eq(i).addClass('right').outerHeight(true);
    } else {
        left_column_height+= items.eq(i).outerHeight(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same question, and Mark's answer didn't work for me.

However, [This method worked for me](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/01/facebook-timeline-design-using-jquery.html)

[You can see it in action in this Fidddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pKFBp/21/)

I hope it helps you or anyone else! :)