# Stacking divs with variable height in 2 columns like Facebook Timeline

Tags: css, html

I want to create a natural flow of content. The problem that I now face is that the `<div>`s will only line up next to each other. They will not pass the bottom edge of the floated block on the opposite side.

The following illustration clearly shows the problem. Let's say that I have 4 `<div>`s with variable heights:

- Div1 always starts left
- Div2 always is displayed on the right side
- Div3 is on the left or right side, depending on the hight of Div1 and Div2
- Div4 in this situation, Div4 doesn't stick to Div2's bottom
- Div5 the same problem occurs

So, the position of the `divs > Div2` should be determined by the height of the previous divs. Could you please advise me on how to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Care to give us a link where we can look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked on this last night and found a rather simple way to do.

Compare the bottom position of the left column and the right column, append the new li element to the side with smaller value, which can be done by th e following way:

```
var last_left_post = $('.left:last');
var last_right_post = $('.right:last');
var left_position = 0;
var right_position = 0;

left_position = last_left_post.height() + last_left_post.offset().top;
right_position = last_right_post.height() + last_right_post.offset().top;

if(left_position<=right_position){
    $('#timeline').append('<li class="left"></li>');
}else{
    $('#timeline').append('<li class="right"></li>');
}
```

.left and .right using the same css as you do.

Answer (score 12):

After checking the Facebook CSS and HTML, I found they achieve this using a `list` and alternating the `float` on the `li` elements between `left` and `right` (ie, every even element is floated right)

For example:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li:nth-child(2n) {
    clear: right;
    float: right;
}
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gBVPj/**

This approach only works if an element on one side does not exceed the height of two elements on the other side. For example, in your diagram, should box 2 have a height larger than that of box 1 and 3 combined, then box 5 will be displaced and positioned inline with box 4.

**Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gBVPj/1/**

I have not found an example of this problem on Facebook (one element never exceeds the height of two) so I believe that they have taken this into account. They could possibly be achieving this by using JavaScript - if you check the elements, they have a property `data-height` which matches the height of the element.

Comment: I've found several elements: `data-side`, `data-fixed`, `data-size` and `data-height`. Guess I gonna check the JS files of Facebook. Will add it to this post when found to make it useful for others as well.

Comment: @Mr.Pallazzo Sounds like a good plan. I'll take a look as well.

Comment: TThis won't also work if element on the right is shorter than element of the same "level" on the left like this: http://jsfiddle.net/skF2A/ . I would really love to know how facebook handles that.

Comment: @PiotrJakubowski You are right. My guess would be that Facebook are using the `data-height` field to calculate whether the next `<li>` element should be floated `left` or `right` as this would resolve most of the issues.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts Yeah, I think you're right. Just in case if someone is looking for an easy way to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191015/how-do-i-lay-out-my-content-divs-in-a-similar-manner-to-facebook-timeline

Comment: actually, this works only as long as no div on the right side is higher than the one on the left.