# CSS Float position issue

Tags: css, positioning, css-float

I know there are tons of questions regarding floats, but I seem to be a bit stuck on how to overcome this problem.

See my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/eE9WT/1/

What I am trying to do (or infact, trying to avoid) is the third .float div starting once the second .float div has started.

I would prefer the third div to fall directly underneath the first, making use of all space on the page. I'm aware that I could separate this into two columns, but I was wondering if there is a better solution without having to do that.

Believe it or not, within my 5 years of developing for the web this seems to be the first time I've been faced with this problem!

Thanks guys

Comment: This answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9141944/681807

Comment: Guys thanks alot for the help. After crawling through some Stackoverflow discussions about this, it seems that this plugin has the solution:

http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html

Bit of a pain to have to resort to a plugin, but it does the job very well. This jsfiddle seemed to be the closest I got before discovering the plugin:

http://jsfiddle.net/gK2Vn/

Problem with this is that if you have content in your floated divs it doesn't seem to extend the height of the divs. If there is anyone who could perhaps build upon this jsfiddle that would be great, as they got very close!

Comment: Is that not just because you are setting `height` rather than `min-height` when setting random div heights in your Javascript? http://jsfiddle.net/gK2Vn/1/

Answer (score 0):

This article would help in creating a Floating Box Layout: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/floating-boxes-css-layout.htm

Also check out his other layouts, just in case they seem a better fit for your design!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a rule for the second float to be right

```
.float + .float {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution you are looking for:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3SwJx/1/)

I moved all the div's to the left with `float`.
Made some space in the right side of the screen with `padding-right` on the container.
And then used the `position: relative;` to moved the second column to that space.

Answer (score 0):

```
Display:inline-block;
zoom:-1;
```

More than float it do something for you. Only some rare case am using float. I know this is not meet your goal, I just explore my side.