# How to make 2 column stacked floating divs

Tags: css, css-float

I am looking to stack divs in 2 columns, like [facebook timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141502/stacking-divs-with-variable-height-in-2-columns-like-facebook-timeline) but I want to do it using pure CSS only. I currently have [this but the margin is not correct on Content Four](http://jsfiddle.net/ACVvw/).

```
#container { width: 700px; background-color: green; }
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #cecece;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.odd { float: left; }
.even { float: right; }
```

The rule is that the divs will have equal widths, and should go to the shorter column when floating.

Is there a *reliable* pure CSS solution or do I have to resort to JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
#container { width:700px; background-color: green; display:table; }
.box {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #cecece;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```