# Some trouble with a HTML / CSS Timeline effect

Tags: html, css, timeline

I'm trying to a timeline effect on a project. I made some research and found [this exemple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9141944/195999)

And, as you can see [here](http://labs.a.rnaud.be/testTL/), it doesn't work well... Here is the part which made it :

```
section#lastPost {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto; }
section#lastPost .TLItem {
  clear: left;
  float: left; }
section#lastPost .TLItem:nth-child(2n) {
  clear: right;
  float: right; }
```

Well, as you can see, there is a little space problem :)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to know the height of each block to short it out. Your answer relies in this post:
[How do I lay out my content divs in a similar manner to Facebook Timeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191015/how-do-i-lay-out-my-content-divs-in-a-similar-manner-to-facebook-timeline)

And you can see the working fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/gK2Vn/

In a way you need to add the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var left_column_height = 0;
    var right_column_height = 0;
    var items = $('section#lastPost #TL .TLItem');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (left_column_height > right_column_height) {
            right_column_height += items.eq(i).addClass('right').outerHeight(true);
                        } 
        else {
            left_column_height += items.eq(i).outerHeight(true);
        }
    }
});
```

And change your CSS to:

```
section#lastPost #TL .TLItem {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
}
section#lastPost #TL .TLItem.right {
    clear: right;
    float: right;
}
```